# How can I programatically force Windows XP to display thumbnails for a folder?

Tags: windows-xp, view, directory, thumbnails, shellexecute

I have an application that calls `ShellExecute` with a folder path. This brings up the folder in explorer.

However, I want to make sure that the folder is set to display the contents in thumbnail view. How can I ensure this happens?